# Error in input pipeline using queues in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, fifo

I am getting this error for the below mentioned code. Kindly help me out with this.
This code is printing variables number of batches everytime I run this code. I am unable to figure out the error.

> OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue
>   '_2_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements
>   (requested 15, current size 0)     [[Node: batch =
>   QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
import os

batch_size = 16 
min_queue = 256


def load_image():
    length = calculate_size("./Coco_subset_5356")

    names = tf.train.match_filenames_once("./Coco_subset_5356/*.jpg")

    # Extracted names from the file  
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(names)

    #Initialised the File reader
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    my_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value, channels = 3)
    my_img = tf.image.resize_images(my_img, [256,256])
    my_img.set_shape((256,256,3))


    print(length)

    images = tf.train.batch(
      [my_img],
      batch_size=batch_size,
      num_threads=1,
      capacity=min_queue + 3*batch_size)

     print(images)

with tf.Session() as sess:  
    #sess.run(init_op)  
    tf.local_variables_initializer().run()
    #print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES))

    #For coordination between queue runner and the reader
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord = coord)
    for j in range(length/batch_size):
        #optimizer.run(feed_dict={input_batch: images[i])
        x = sess.run(images)    
        print(j)
        print(x.shape)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

def calculate_size(img_dir):
    file = []
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(img_dir):
        for i in files:
            i = os.path.join(img_dir, i)
            file.append(i)
        length = len(file)
    return length

load_image()
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and in my case it was some images not getting correctly decoded (in my dataset I had 1x1 pixel images that managed to get through the filtering process..). Are you certain *all* your images can be correctly opened and decoded as jpg files? (They also must not be truncated, tensorflow by default will throw an error when processing truncated images)

Comment: What is the number of *.jpg files in the directory? Is it a multiple of 15? What if you set `allow_smaller_final_batch=True` in `tf.train.batch` method?

Comment: Also would you mind editing your question to make the error more readable (e.g. using the > mark)?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is not a proper answer, but I can't post code in a comment and this might point you in the right direction.

As anticipated in my comment to the question, I had the very same error on one of my datasets. In my case, the problem was the fact that **not all images in my dataset could be decoded as jpg files**. Truncated images and, in my case, 1x1 pixel images were hidden in my data and whenever I'd try to prcess the dataset I'd have the queues closing reporting errors I had a hard time fiding.

I solved the problem writing a small filter script that goes through all files one-by-one and logs those it cannot process:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import glob

image_data_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string)

filenames = glob.glob(r'C:\my_test_folder\*.jpg')
decoded_img_op = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_data_placeholder)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for fn in filenames:
    with open(fn, 'rb') as fp:
      image_data = fp.read()
    try:
      sess.run(decoded_img_op, feed_dict={image_data_placeholder:image_data})
    except:
      # log the filename o the broken image (or delete/move/etc)
      print('Cannot decode file {}'.format(fn))
```

It's not the most efficient of implementations, but it was good enough for my use-case.